Function takes progressively longer to execute over time C#
I have been trying to trace down a memory leak in my program and every method I have timed thus far has been as predicted and constant except for this one. As I leave the program running the time to execute the IsValid() method takes progressively longer as the program runs, gaining 1ms every 30 seconds or so. I am using StopWatch to time the execution of the function and I am only iterating on 1 object that always return true. The GetBestGoal() method is being called 60 times per second and there is only one object in the list of goals for simplicity.
for (int i = 0; i < goals.Count; i++)
        {
            planStopwatch.Start();
            isvalid = goals[i].IsValid(blackBoard, worldState);
            planStopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Time: {planStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            if (isvalid)
            {
                int goalPriority = goals[i].Priority(blackBoard, worldState);

                if (goalPriority > hightPriority)
                {
                    best = goals[i];
                    hightPriority = goalPriority;
                }
            }
        }

public override bool IsValid(BlackBoard blackBoard, WorldState worldState)
    {
        return true;
    }

I have tried benchmarking all other methods in the program and IsValid() is the only one that doesn't have a constant execution time.
code

From the code you posted, you have initialized the StopWatch outside of the loop and you don't Reset it after you take a measurement in each iteration. So it really just accumulates the ElapsedMilliseconds.
So something like this:
var planStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    planStopWatch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    planStopWatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Time: {planStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    // planStopWatch.Reset(); uncomment to have it "working"
}

Time: 8 ms
Time: 18 ms
Time: 28 ms
Time: 38 ms
Time: 48 ms
Time: 58 ms
Time: 68 ms
Time: 78 ms
Time: 88 ms
Time: 98 ms


Thats interesting, I've used the same method of timing other parts of my code and it worked fine.

@Terrence it looked like it worked fine.

Well, resetting the Timer fixed my "memory leak", thankyou.

Alternatively, change Start() to Restart() (this has slightly different behavior, though, as the stopwatch will retain the elapsed time of the final loop execution).
